# Why is iterating over a non-mutable Vec of non-mutable non-copyable elements legal in Rust?

Tags: rust

Consider this example code:

```
let strings: Vec<String> = something;
for s in strings {
    // uses `s`, the elements of `strings` are moved into `s`
}
```

`strings` is not mutable. However, the elements of `strings` are moved into `s` for every iteration of the `for` loop.

Why is this valid Rust code? The `Vec` is not mutable. I would have expected this to prevent moving its elements.

What did I not understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, mutability in Rust (not talking about mutability of references but of values) is not a property of the value but of the binding. Once you move a value, its mutability can be changed. For example:

```rust
let v = vec![1]; // Immutable.
let mut v2 = v; // Now mutable.
v2.push(2);
let v3 = v2; // Now again immutable.
```

The `for` loop moves the container (via the implicit [`IntoIterator::into_iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#tymethod.into_iter) call), so it can be declared as mutable.

Second, the container instance itself isn't mutated, an iterator is created from it and it is mutated. And if you'll look at the desugaring of the `for` loop (click "Show HIR" in the playground) you'll see it binds the iterator as `mut iter`.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a vector with `for x in y` doesn't mutate it nor borrow it's element. It destructs the vector and takes ownership of each element.

Answer (score 1):

You are not mutating the vector; you are disposing of it.

When you use a `for` loop, there is an implicit call to `.into_iter()`. This moves the vector, so it is no longer accessible through the variable `strings`; if you try using `strings` after the loop (or inside the loop), you'll get an error like this:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `strings`
```

So even if you mutate the strings inside the loop, the mutation will never be visible through the variable `strings`, because the mutation occurs after moving out of the vector.